# How can I install Emacs25.2 on openSuse?

Tags: install, build

On Ubuntu I would install emacs dependencies with `apt-get build-dep emacs24`, extract the emacs25.2.tar.gz and install but the dependencies don't seem to be on openSuse's zypper (package manager).

Atm I'm getting this when trying to install emacs25.2

```
configure: error: You seem to be running X, but no X development libraries
were found.  You should install the relevant development files for X
and for the toolkit you want, such as Gtk+ or Motif.  Also make
sure you have development files for image handling, i.e.
tiff, gif, jpeg, png and xpm.
If you are sure you want Emacs compiled without X window support,   pass
 --without-x
```

How should I go about getting that dependency and other dependencies needed for emacs on openSuse?

Comment: Please disclose posts in related forums so that we don't spin our wheels unnecessarily:  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/6misud/how_can_i_install_emacs252_on_opensuse/?st=j4yxbick&sh=dd1e0ca6  This way, forum participants can read what other people have already said elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

emacs 25.2 is already available in the [`editors` repo](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/editors/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/editors.repo). See [these instructions](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Add_package_repositories) on how to add it.

EDIT: [Other openSUSE releases](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/editors/) are available for the same repo.

Comment: I've added the repo, went back to Software Management. I still see only emacs 24.3

Comment: After looking around I see that there was a "Versions" tab after highlighting the emacs package where the new version shows up after adding that repo.

Comment: The link to the *editors* repository returns a *The requested URL is no longer available on this server and there is no forwarding address.* error.

Comment: No. The questioner is not interested on installing emacs, but installing the build dependencies required by emacs so that you can build emacs from sources and install it manually without employing the package manager for installing emacs.

Comment: It is not clear to me whether @tyler wants to install dependencies or emacs itself. He posted the way he would do it in Ubuntu, but it is not clear whether that's _one of many_ ways he could do it or the _one way_ he would do it

Answer (score 0):

The command for installing build dependencies only for emacs is:

```
zypper source-install --build-deps-only emacs
```

NOTE: You may need to enable sources repository in YAST.

Shameless self promotion: [This script](https://github.com/frgomes/bash-scripts/blob/feature/0057-overhaul_turn_functions_onto_shell_scripts/bin/install_emacs) downloads the latest version of emacs, automagically installs dependencies (for Debian and openSUSE), builds it, installs under a folder you can configure and finally creates symbolic links onto your $HOME/bin.